# wcf: dynamically call service which return composite type

Tags: c#, wcf

So I have a situation like this: `A` needs to call `B` service and `A` gets to know only `B` address and only at runtime. But both have same service contract in advance.

So far I have this (at `A`):

```
    using (ChannelFactory<IService1> scf = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "B's adress"))
    {
        var channel = scf.CreateChannel();
        channel.GetData(5);
        ...
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    { 
       [DataMember]
       public bool BoolValue
        ...

       [DataMember]
       public string StringValue
        ...
    }
```

`B` exposes same service contract.

Now the question. With `GetData` everything works fine, but with `GetDataUsingDataContract` which takes and returns composite type - it seems that `B` receives object with default values and not what has been sent. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is `CompositeType` defined in assembly C that is used by both A and B? If not, where is it defined?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth It's defined in the same way both at A and B. Hm, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Good :-) I posted it as an answer, please upvote and accept, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `CompositeType` into an assembly C and reference that in A and B.